# React Native SectionList replace data key

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming, react-native-sectionlist

I am fairly new to React and React native, but I have bumped into a problem when populating a `SectionList` and could not find a solution yet.

I have an array of objects, and each object has it's own array. A SectionList is ideal to display this info, however, the array for each section is not called "data", while `SectionList` seems to expect the key "data" for the array in each section.

Is there a way to tell the `SectionList` to use another key instead of the data key to populate each section's array?

Answer (score 1):

As Per my Knowledge on [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist) each Section will Expect a data and Key .

What you can do is modify your Data as per that.

like for Eg : 
your data is [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7]]

what you can do is iterate through this array and push each subArray into New Array With Format {key:index,data:subArray}

hope this will Help :)

Comment: Its an extra processing involved.... .there should be an option to provide the key that holds the array instead of hardcoding it to "data"

Comment: i do agree with your point and there should be a prop where you can provide key of array,  will try to discuss it further in react native discussion.

Comment: Is there really no solution to this? Everyone is just out there beating their data to be inside a `data` key?...

Comment: yes for now there is no solution. Someone can always try to implement it and send a PR. I wanted to do it but faced challenges in setting up for contributing. if someone can help me with that i will try implement it and send a PR.